# Android not finding files in R.raw

Tags: android, kotlin, media-player

[image]

I can't figure out why it is not recognizing my audio files. I tried to different types of audio files so that does not seem to be the problem. Any ideas? I am inside a private method if that matters at all

Comment: try use lower case letters for audio files

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks!

Comment: Well done.. I have posted it as answer, please mark it as the solution to help others who might have the same issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you should use lower case letters for audio files instead of upper case letters

for using uppercase letters you will get below error

[image]